# What to do about this makePSOCKcluster error?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm running a function called mixedpower() that lets you simulate power at different sample sizes. However I get the following error and don't know how to handle it!

```
Error in makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...) : 
  Cluster setup failed. 11 of 11 workers failed to connect.
```

Here is a reproducible example. (Just to head off any comments, I know that gear shouldn't be a random variable here, but I'm just using it for the purpose of this example.)

```
#You can download the mixedpower package like this.
  if (!require("devtools")) {
    install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)}

   devtools::install_github("DejanDraschkow/mixedpower") 

library(mixedpower)
library(lme4)

m <- lmer(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + (1|gear), data = mtcars)

mtcars$gear_num <- as.numeric(mtcars$gear)

power <- mixedpower(model = m, data = mtcars, fixed_effects = c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat"), simvar = "gear_num", steps = c(3, 4, 5), critical_value = 2)
```

And if it is helpful I am running RStudio version 1.1.453 on MacOS Mojave version 10.14.6.

Comment: Your code works for me on Ubuntu/r-devel. (It appears to use all available cores by default, which is anti-social/bad practice ... more alarmingly, there's no immediately obvious way to set it to run in serial/with fewer cores!).  (Your RStudio version is **probably** irrelevant, although it wouldn't hurt to try your code outside of RStudio  in a plain R console or terminal.)

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692

Answer (score 0):

I can't test but strongly suspect that your problem is related to a bug in recent versions of R (now patched in more recent versions). [This issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692) describes a workaround of adding the following to your `.Rprofile` file (it's also possible that updating to the latest patched version of R would do it).

```r
## WORKAROUND: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692
## Revert to 'sequential' setup of PSOCK cluster in RStudio Console on macOS and R 4.0.0
if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1" && !nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_TERM")) && 
    Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Darwin" && getRversion() >= "4.0.0") {
  parallel:::setDefaultClusterOptions(setup_strategy = "sequential")
}
```